# Ширина input range в Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, input

Почему размер этого элемента в FF гораздо больше, чем в других браузерах?
Даже прописав размер отдельно в css, я наблюдаю отличие в размерах в FF

Можно ли как-нибудь это исправить?

Comment: после принудительного указания width у меня все стало одинаковой ширины.

Answer (score 1):

Укажите

```
box-sizing: border-box;
width:<your value>;
height:<your value>;
padding:<your value>;
```

см. http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

Задавайте height полю и тогда размер везде будет одинаковым.